# What to use for RTL , bidi embed or override?

Tags: right-to-left

I am adapting my site to RTL languages. And I am not sure if I should use

```
    .rtl p{
        direction: rtl;
        unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    }
//or 
    .rtl2 p{
        direction: rtl;
        unicode-bidi:embed;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9hf7/3/

but as suggested here
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/unicode-bidi/
and few other sites we should use

```
direction: rtl;
unicode-bidi:embed;
```

By looking at the test this just aligns it to the right .

**I might be wrong here since since I dont understand the language used in the demo**

But in both cases class `.rtl` and `.rtl2` chars are in the same place.

Can someone who actually speaks any of the RTL languages enlighten me here please and advise what is the  right way.

Thank you!